# WP .js script file not loading

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I have looked all over the place and did not find a solution to my problem.

I have a child theme where I have a functions.php file where I try to register and enqueue the script the following way:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('my_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri('js/scripts.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('my_scripts');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

And here is the script I am trying to load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("test");
})
```

I made sure I have a "js" folder in my child directory where my scripts.js is.

But for some reason, this is not working for me.

Any one got an idea?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to codex, [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) does not including a trailing slash. So, you might want to use it in the following way:

```
function wpb_adding_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('my_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('my_scripts');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_scripts' );
```

### UPDATE

If you want to use jQuery in your scripts, you should do it in one of these ways:

1. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` to avoid conflict
2. Create a self invoking function and pass `$` to it.

Take a look at this example:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      alert("test");
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :). Unfortunately, it is not working for me :(. Is it because I am on localhost? I tried several browsers.. Another question: where I have 'my_scripts', from my understanding I can name that whatever I like, correct?

Comment: 1) Can you please elaborate 'not working'? What happens? Isn't your js file queued? does it have a wrong URL? or? 2) Yes you can name it anything you wish, as long as it doesn't conflict with any other scripts.

Comment: @SergeInácio Also there was a mistype in my code, sorry. I forgot to add a `/` to the end of the code. Try the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again, but still no luck. what I mean by not working, is that the `alert('test')` is not firing. Other functions in the function.php file work

Comment: @SergeInácio That's strange. Any error log in console? Does it print the script in your theme's header? If so, is it the correct path?

Comment: I checked in chrome and found this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/ausgerechnet-islam/wp-content/themes/responsive-brix-premium-child/js/scripts.js?ver=1.1"></script>`. So it seems to be loading. I guess there is a problem with my jQuery code?

Comment: @SergeInácio That's right. I didn't notice you are using dollar sign. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948053/jquery-function-not-working-on-wordpress). This worked, it seemed to have conflicts... If you post this in your answer I will mark your answer as accepted with pleasure ;). Thanks for all your help :).

Comment: this worked as well. Answer accepted :).